# How to setup a Jenkins job for Veracode Scan in a Node application?

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, veracode

My Jenkins runs on AWS EC2 instance and I'm creating a freestyle job to run Veracode Scan. I configured my Veracode portal API credentials with the Job. Installed the Veracode Jenkins plugin as well. And the Git repo also set upped in the pipeline. So my plan was to Zip the git repo by running below shell script
[image]

Then in the post build section I configured to upload the zip file like shown in below image.
[image]

When i build the job it throws below error.
[image]
it says that zip is not found. What may be the reason for this error? Also am I approaching this in a correct way?

Comment: The reason its failing is because you do not have the zip binary installed on your agent ( in this case your controller).  You need to do an "yum install zip"  before you trigger the usage of the zip command. 
Also its never safe to run jobs on your controller( also called master). Always use an agent to process the jobs instead of on controller.

Regarding the question on the usage of the Veracode Scan via Jenkins, I would prefer to follow the code examples as published by Veracode [here](https://docs.veracode.com/r/t_jenkins_pipe) based on different use-cases. 

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: are you saying that i need to install zip in my EC2 instance first?

Comment: yes, it either needs zip to be installed or if its already installed, it needs to be added to the PATH var.

Comment: How do i check if it's already added to the PATH? or How to add the Zip to the path?

Comment: To check whats in the PATH var, just use `echo $PATH` and the output would look like this - `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/centos/.local/bin:/home/centos/bin`
If you do a `yum install zip` (or `sudo yum install zip` if you dont have root access ) it installs in `/usr/bin` by default and this path should already be part of your PATH var. 

To add zip to PATH: 
`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/zip`